# Devel's dsm & dpm not working

Tags: debugging

I am trying to print out the $view object using devel and dsm.

My function in function.php is

```
function my_theme_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name == 'my-view') {
     dsm('$view'); 
  }
}
```

But I just get this message below, there is nothing inside the message, the html is

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-success" data-thmr="thmr_137">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
  <h4 class="element-invisible">Status message</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><pre>$view</pre></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are dsm'ing a string, try `dsm($view);`

Comment: whoops.. Ok now I'm getting a php Allowed memory size error, so I guess that its working now I just need to increase memory

Answer (score 0):

use [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) instead like written here [dsm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7)